# How do I Unmarshal an Elasticsearch JSON Response?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data

I am using the Spring Rest Template to call a REST endpoint that houses the ElasticSearch (ES) cluster instance. I have NO access to the ES cluster instance. This is why I cannot use Spring Data ES, nor could I use the Java Rest Highlevel Client. I only have access through the REST endpoint which accepts Query DSL in the post request, and provides the raw JSON response that the ES Instance uses.

I would like to know, in this situation, what is the best approach to get an unmarshalled version of the JSON search response from the REST endpoint? I tried to use the SearchResponse object that Elastic Search provides, but the Rest Template barfed with the following exception.

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchResponse]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchResponse` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 2]
```

Here is a snippet of the response

```
{
    "took": 1034,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 608,
        "successful": 608,
        "skipped": 542,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 17,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "some-index",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "some-id",
                "_score": null,
                "_source": {
...
```

Comment: Why you can not use Java HLC or Spring data ? you are calling API using Elastic URL and authentication details right then that is suffeciant for Java HLC and spring data.

Comment: @SagarPatel - I cannot call using Spring Data or Java HLC because the ES Clusters are not available for me to call. I only have access through a separate REST layer that accepts Query DSL as the body of the request. I have tried to use them both, and they complain that my REST endpoint is NOT the ES cluster instance.

Comment: ok got it.. You have intermiddiate layer or proxy layer and request is going through it. If this is the case then you can not use `SearchResponse` object as well. You need to conver response to `JsonObject` then you can peform other task like getting document or hit etc.